# Which is the "safest" system cleaner in the repository?

Tags: system, cleanup

I have a small Hard Drive (20 gb) so I need to keep an eye on my Disk Usage Analyzer, I can't afford to upgrade my Hard Drive yet so I'm looking for a safe and effective system cleaner that won't compromise system stability.

Comment: You don't need a specific application for that, just check the existing answers to http://askubuntu.com/questions/21587/how-do-i-clean-up-my-harddrive .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**BleachBit** [image: Install bleachbit]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bleachbit)

[Read more about it here](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/)