# kruft: why do i gain 1GB each time i do a distribution upgrade

Tags: upgrade, disk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clean up my harddrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21587/how-do-i-clean-up-my-harddrive)

Every 5 months I start running out of space on my root partition...
  I scramble to erase documentation, remove log files, and keep only a single kernel so as to keep enough space.
And then every time I run a distribution upgrade (cdromupgrade) I end up with about a gig more space even though it keeps all the same programs installed.

Anyone know where the kruft is?

Comment: I'll try the recommendations in the link but I won't have an answer for a while since I just installed 11.4.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to run `sudo du -x --max-depth=1 / | sort -n` to see where your space is going.  You can walk the directories to get a better idea where the space is going.  I generally find the space ends up being in few directories.

You may want to try running `sudo apt-get clean` to remove all the debs from the cache directory.  The directory `/var/cache/apt/archives` can grow quite large if you don't clean it out.  Once the packages are installed, you don't need the `.deb` archived.  They are helpful if you need to reinstall the package, or find the original version of a file that was installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` which may free up some space.  Normally the update manager should do this for you but perhaps cdromupgrade doesn't.

Comment: i do this regularly in order to keep enough breathing space.

Comment: the problem is not with cdromupgrade.  the upgrade is what frees the space.  the problem is with the updates and the normal running of the system over the 5 months.

Answer (score 0):

[KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) is a fairly direct way of finding where all your space is going.