# How can I free up disk space by removing files that aren't needed?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, disk-usage

How can we free disk space by removing unwanted data on the system? How do we detect that the files are not necessary for the programs to work?

Comment: Related: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/q/89710/40581) and [Hot to find and visualize filesystem bloat](http://askubuntu.com/a/21595/40581)

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend the same as Jo-Erlend but there is also a little bit of cleaning with the download packages that you already have installed.

For example with the command `aptitude` or `apt-get` you can do this:

`sudo apt-get clean` - Erase downloaded package files
`sudo apt-get autoclean` - Erase old downloaded package files

`sudo aptitude clean` - Erase downloaded package files
`sudo aptitude autoclean` - Erase old downloaded package files

You also have the tool **Ubuntu-Tweak**:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Then run ubuntu-tweak. It has an option for cleaning up called Janitor:

[image]

Lastly you have Bleachbit (Or ChlorineByte ^^) which has several [FEATURES](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/features) which include cleaning the cache from Firefox, Temp files for more than 50 programs and other stuff that is mentioned in the Features page.

The **Software Center** comes with version 0.8.8 and the Official Page has the 0.9. Whichever you use will do the trick since the difference between version is [SMALL](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-090).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [disk usage analyzer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/baobab/) to see what is using space. It is installed by default.

[image]

You should not delete things outside of your home directory unless you know what you're doing. Before you delete things, it is a good idea to rename them to see if everything still works. When you know that it does, then you can safely delete them.