# How to clean up unnecessary files

Tags: hard-drive

Please suggest me any particular unnecessary file that I can clean to back everything to normal condition(temporarily). (i.e. any log or archieve or anything ). My var/log has only 40MB and Home directory has 3GB of space(so I believe that's not a problem). Other than that what I can clean up to make space.

```
[user@host]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_inamivm-lv_root
                       18G   17G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   71M  389M  16% /boot
```

Comment: Possilbe duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21587/how-do-i-clean-up-my-harddrive?rq=1

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To clean some packages laying around, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

---

If you are in search for a more in depth cleaning, use the [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) Utility.

**Install**

---

The [Ubuntu Tweak Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) by [Ding Zhou](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix), support Ubuntu 7.10 till 14.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

**Usage**

---

Click the `janitor` tab, select what you want to scan, check what you want to delete, and then press the `clean` button to cleanse your system.

[image: ubuntu-tweak-janitor]

Comment: Thank you! Just running `sudo apt-get autoremove` cleared 6.5 GB from my system!

Comment: Is there any terminal based tool like `Ubuntu Tweak`?

Comment: supper helpful!!

Answer (score 9):

The spacesaver technique

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

As well as use the tool **bleachbit** which will be the awesome space saver. It will save atleast 1GB of space and will bring you into surprise. Use the tool in both regular and superuser mode.This can be installed by using the command

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Run the command as

```
sudo bleachbit
bleachbit
```

Comment: can `bleachbit ` run without a gui?

Answer (score 3):

I have made a python script to clean Debian based Distros.

Here is the link : [OS Cleaner](https://github.com/jspw/Cleaner)

#### This sript will clear the :

- packages that are no longer required
- Clean up APT cache
- systemd journal logs
- Clean the thumbnail cache

You can also check the garbage storages!

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked trimming logs also did nothing.
Being a long time nodejs usage on this system I also use 'n' to install latest version of node. I found a way to purge the old versions.

```
n prune
```

This returned 25% of an 8G VDI