# How to increase size of my root?

Tags: partitioning, cleanup

The root of my disk is showing 222 MB and rest others are in GBs. See:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             14G     0   14G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.8G  174M  2.6G   7% /run
/dev/sda1        83G   78G  222M 100% /
tmpfs            14G   25M   14G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            14G     0   14G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.8G   92K  2.8G   1% /run/user/1000
```

How can I increase the size of `/dev/sda1` while I am still in the system?

Comment: `df` does not indicate that there is any other partition to borrow drive space from. Please edit your original question to post the output of the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f ;  sudo lsblk -m ; sudo parted -ls` ; If there is no such partition you have only two alternatives: Install more drive space or remove files from your current root file system.

Answer (score 2):

You have only one partition which is used by the user `/` or `/dev/sda1`

This partition have `78GB` used and `222MB` free.

The simple solution will be to remove `junk files` / `temporary files` from `/dev/sda1`

Instructions:

- [how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187326/how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-files)
- [how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Note: As mentioned by @dobey and @sudodus - another easy solution will be:

- Install additional / bigger disk.

Comment: also remove old unused kernels.

Comment: Also just install a bigger disk.