# how do i clean up my computer on ubuntu

Tags: software-center

i run ubuntu 15.04 64 bit on a lenovo y50 and am trying to figure out how to perform a system cleanup. i have very frequently received messages from the OS that there are software updates required, but the latest software update is unable to be installed bc theres not enough space on the disk, which is weird bc i hardly download files on this laptop. i have looked into a few different details, like computer janitor, but the ubuntu software center says the program doesnt exist. and whenever i try downloading ubuntu tweak it says that some files failed to download and i see a wall of error messages

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clean up my harddrive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21587/how-do-i-clean-up-my-harddrive) and [What trusted file cleaning tools are available for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389026/what-trusted-file-cleaning-tools-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Check  output of `df` command and then `sudo du` command. First will tell you how much space you've left on the drive, second will tell you what files take the most space.  It'd be nice if you provided those in the question as well

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for cleaning your OS is using bleachbit.

1. Install it `sudo apt-get install bleachbit`
2. Run it as root `sudo bleachbit`
3. Check all checkboxes and press `clean` button.

   ***Note:***  Bleachbit warns after checking some checkboxes, it's better you
   don't check those that bleachbit says is slow or harmful operation.